# SQL view is pretty slow. Do you see any problem is the view

Tags: sql, sql-server

We've created an SQL view. However, when I query the view it takes more than 10 minutes to return a single entry. Do you see any problem with the view? How can we troubleshoot a performance issue? Is there a best practice for creating the view

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_mytestview]
AS
    SELECT        
        Table1.SERVICE_LINE_DESCR, Table1.SUB_SERVICE_LINE_CD, 
        Table1.SUB_SERVICE_LINE_DESCR, Table1.SL_COMPANY_ID, 
        Table1.SL_DEPARTMENT_ID, Table1.SL_SUB_AREA, Table1.DELETE_FLAG, 
        Table1.SL_RANK_CD, Table1.SL_RANK_DESCR, 
        Table1.SL_COMM, Table1.EMPL_STATUS, Table1.GBL_ASSIGNEE_IND, 
        Table1.SL_EXCL_INCL_FL, Table1.SL_MC_CTRY_2CHAR, 
        Table1.SL_IND_SEGMENT_CD, Table1.SL_GD_STATUS, Table1.SL_DOMAIN, 
        Table1.SL_MAILING_ADDR, Table1.SL_CODED_MAIL_ADDR, 
        Table1.START_DATE, Table1.HIRE_DT, Table1.DATETIME_STAMP, 
        Table2.samaccountname
    FROM            
        dbo.mytesttable AS Table1 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.vw_otherone AS Table2 ON Table1.colum1 COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = Table2.colum1 COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
    WHERE        
        (Table2.samaccountname IS NOT NULL) 
        AND (Table1.SL_DISPLAY_NAME IS NOT NULL) 
        AND (Table1.SL_ACCOUNT_TYPE IS NOT NULL) 
        AND (Table1.SL_FIRST_NAME IS NOT NULL) 
        AND (Table1.SL_LAST_NAME IS NOT NULL) 

GO
```

Comment: A view, in and of itself, is not slow. The query that uses the view is. To understand why it is slow you review the execution plan. Perhaps a real problem here is that your design allows lots of garbage into the database - otherwise you wouldn't need to filter for all of those blank columns. The use of different collations is also a sign that the design of the database needs help.

Answer (score 3):

It is almost impossible to say, because your view references another view.

However, this condition is *highly suspicious*:

```
ON Table1.GPN COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = Table2.GPN COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

Changing the collation can prevent the use of indexes.  Two columns used as `JOIN` keys should already have compatible collations.  If not, fix your data model!

And, depending on how many of your fields are "empty", you might be able to filter more efficiently.  However, that would only be true if the `WHERE` conditions remove a significant number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Can use an index on your key columns (present in where condition) else the view doesnt have any problem